# any way for the web page itself to turn off spellcheck in iPad Safari?

Tags: ipad, spell-checking

My app is a full-text search interface for ancient texts.  The input is always going to be an ancient word.  iPad Safari insists on pointing out that it is not correctly spelled  -- for modern English, which it ain't.

Chrome honors this, iPad Safari does not:

```
  <input type="text" spellcheck="false" >
```

Is there something analogous for Safari? I think the user can turn off spellcheck globally on the iPad but they shouldn't have to do so to work with my web-app.

```
 <RANT> 
   I'm getting pretty fed up with all of this "built-in so-called intelligence" which is based
   on a very narrow set of assumptions about what the user is actually doing with the browser. 
 </RANT>
```

As Hamlet says to Horatio:

```
 There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,
 Than are dreamt of in your philosophy.
```

Answer (score 2):

Found :  autocorrect=off

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the 'spellcheck' property was unsupported initially in Safari 3 (from the bug ticket http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14552).

But it looks as though they fixed it in a subsequent version - I can see that it's working okay on my Desktop version 4.0.5.

My guess is that the iPad version of Safari isn't up to date enough for this fix, but I presume it will come soon!

Comment: let's hope the fix comes to iPad!  I appreciate your taking the time to reply, and the link to the original bug report.

Comment: I've tested on iOS 7.0.3 and the attribute spellcheck is not supported. Safari iOS doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the input language you're expecting?

```
<input type="text" lang="enm">
```

Enm is Middle English (1100-1500), or you could try ang which is Old English (ca. 450-1100).  I'm expecting iPad doesn't have a dictionary for either, but you never know.  [Full list of tags is here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry), [introduction to language tags here](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/).